# Javascritpt change class to a div near to his grand-father

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I want to dynamically change the class of the element `#sidePanel` from `.compact` to `.expanded`, in this code:

```
<div id="sidePanel" class="compact"></div>
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="buttonContainer">
        <div id="button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm stuck here, I can't apply the class to the correct `<div>`, I can just add the class to the topbar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").mouseover(function(){
    $("this").parent().eq(2).addClass(".expanded").removeClass(".compact");
    });
});
```

I also tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").mouseover(function(){
    $("#sidepanel").addClass(".expanded").removeClass(".compact");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example was pretty close. When you `$.addClass()` and `$.removeClass()`, or are referring to classnames outside of using a selector to target something, just reference the class name (no need for the leading `.`). Also JS (and CSS) are case-sensitive, so `$('#sidepanel')` won't target `#sidePanel` - the cases need to match.

```js
    $("#button").mouseover(function() {
      $("#sidePanel").addClass("expanded").removeClass("compact");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>.expanded {color: red;}</style>
<div id="sidePanel" class="compact">sidepanel</div>
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="buttonContainer">
        <div id="button">button</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your first example, `$(this)` is how you reference `this` in jQuery. If you put `this` in quotes, the word `this` is treated as a string literal instead. And since to use `$.parent()` you would need to go up 2 levels, you should use `$.parents()` with the ID of the parent you want to target, then use `$.prev()` to select the previous element, which is `#sidePanel`. So to traverse the DOM like that, this is how I would do it.

```js
$("#button").mouseover(function() {
      $(this).parents('#topbar').prev().removeClass('compact').addClass('expanded');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>.expanded {color: red;}</style>
<div id="sidePanel" class="compact">sidepanel</div>
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="buttonContainer">
        <div id="button">button</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation

Answer (score 1):

### Your problem is you used `$("#sidepanel")` instead of `$("#sidePanel")`

*Here's a working example after the change is made:*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").on('mouseover', function(){
       $("#sidePanel").addClass("expanded").removeClass("compact");
    });
});
```

```css
#topbar > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#sidePanel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
}

#sidePanel.expanded {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidePanel" class="compact"></div>
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="buttonContainer"></div>
    <div id="button"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first: the solution

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").mouseover(function()
    {
         // class names - without the dot
         $("#sidepanel").addClass("expanded").removeClass("compact");
    });
});
```

then: why you were really close on your first attempt

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button").mouseover(function()
    {
        // $(this) selector uses the `this` keyword (not as a string)
        $(this).parent().eq(2).addClass(".expanded").removeClass(".compact");
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).parent()` will only return 1 element, so selecting the third element in a set of one elements will return no elements. You might be thinking of `.parents()`. With `.parents()` you'd still want to select the second parent element, which would be `$(this).parents().eq(1)`. Lastly you'd need to select the previous sibling of that selector to get to the `#sidepanel` element. `$(this).parents().eq(1).prev()`